# Copy and Paste the contents of a file to Upload it in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I have an Angular where User uploads two files and the files are sent to the serve for the processing and server returns the result. But I want a feature, where I can have two text box , user can just copy paste the contents of two files instead of browsing and uploading the file. I have following code:

`app.component.html`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstfile=null;
  second_file = null;
  title = 'first';
  first_content:any
  content_updated:boolean=false;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient){
    this.content_updated=false;

  }

  firstfileupload(event){
    console.log("First file")
    // console.log(event)
    this.firstfile=event.target.files.item(0)
    this.readFileContent(event.currentTarget.files[0]).subscribe(
      content => {
        for(const line of content.split(/[\r\n]+/)) {
          if (line !== '') {          // <-- regex pattern might return an empty line at the EOF
            console.log(line);
          }
        }
      }

    );
    console.log("Control reached here")
    this.content_updated=true;
    if(this.content_updated===true){
      console.log(this.first_content)
    }
  }
  secondfile(event){
    this.second_file=event.target.files[0];
    this.readFileContent(event.currentTarget.files[0]).subscribe(
      content => {
        for(const line of content.split(/[\r\n]+/)) {
          if (line !== '') {          // <-- regex pattern might return an empty line at the EOF
            console.log(line);
          }
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("Second file uploaded")
  }
  onUpload(){
    console.log("Upload button clicked")
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('files',this.firstfile);
    fd.append('files',this.second_file);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000',fd).subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res)
    }

    )
  }
  private readFileContent(file): Observable<any> {
    let result = new Subject<any>();

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const fileContent = e.target.result;
      result.next(fileContent);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);

    return result.asObservable();
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```js
<h1>Upload the files</h1>
<input type="file" (change)="firstfileupload($event)">
<input type="file" (change)="secondfile($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am just taking the input as file from the user and sends to the user. How can I enable the user to just copy paste the contents in a text area and sends the content as a file , to the server. Thanks in advance.

P.S : Please ignore all the extra code, my focus is just how to get the user input , convert to file and send it to server. In the above code I don't have any logic related to my question, I am just taking the file input.

Comment: So you want that data from textarea to be received at server as a file??

Comment: Yes, I want to send the data as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML :-**

```
<div> Input Text Below </div>
<textarea id="fileData" [(ngModel)]="data"></textarea>
<button (click)="sendData()">Send Data</button>
```

**In Ts :-**

```
public data = '';
public sendData() {
  this.http.post('http://localhost:5000',this.data).subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res)
  });
}
```

**In Ts if need to send as a file.**

```
public data = '';
    public sendData() {
      var blob = new Blob(["This is my first text."], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file',blob);
      this.http.post('http://localhost:5000',formData).subscribe(res =>{
          console.log(res)
      });
    }
```

Comment: How will I access the files at the server side ? Until now `fd.append('files',this.firstfile)` I was able to do this and get the files at server side by doing `request.files.getlist('files')`.

Comment: server will get the data in request.body. it will be text now. not file.

Comment: But I want to send it as a file, cause I do not want to make any changes to my server, is there any way i can send the data as file ?.

Comment: Also this is not working, it throws the error that data is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, data error has been removed, but would I send the data as a file ?

Comment: no, as text. in text area you can only have text. not file.

Comment: It throws the following error now `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'.`

Comment: import FormsModule in your module.

Comment: Works fine now. Is there a way i can write  the value of data to a temporary file and send it to the server ?

Comment: no need of it actually. let backend create a new file. text is smaller in size to send to backend as compared to a file.

Comment: I would have to change a lot of code in backend for that, I would rather send files to the backend